# How to submit file through req.files and custom label through req.json in FLASK

Tags: python, flask

My end goal is to have a user submit a file with a custom label through my client in React. Here is the server logic in Flask.

**FLASK ROUTE**

```
@bp.route("/service/<int:service_id>/file-data", methods=["POST"])
# @use_kwargs(service_file_data_schema, location='json')
def add_service_file_data(service_id ):
    file_data = request.files['file_data']
    file_label = request.json['file_label']

    new_file = add_new_service_file_data(service_id, file_data, file_label)


    # res.status_code = 201
    return jsonify(new_file)
```

**ADD_NEW_SERVICE_FILE_DATA**

```
def add_new_service_file_data(service_id, file_data, file_label):

    print(file_data)
    print(file_label)

    # new_file_data = ServiceFile(service_id=service_id, file_data=file_data.read(), file_label=file_label)

    return 'test'
    # try:
    #     db_session.add(new_file_data)
    #     db.commit()

    # except:
    #     db_session.rollback()
    #     message = "Error Occured"
```

I can not return both `file_data` and `file_label` when testing in **Postman** as `file_data` is coming from **form_data** and `file_label` is coming from **raw JSON data** when trying to submit both through **form_data** I receive the following error:

```
file_label = request.json['file_label']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

any advice or resources on a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly, what you want to know is how to receive data from both JSON and FORM simultaneously in your requests? Or you would like to know how to deal with the python error you hare having when data is just in either JSON or FORM but not in both?